# JS - Removing duplicate object in an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

For example I have this array:

```js
0: {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: ""}
1: {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9666-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: ""}
2: {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: "One"}
3: {myfield: "af7401a0-aa6e-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 1, value: "Two"}
```

I wanna be able to loop through it and pop/remove older version of duplicated array, in this example I wanted to keep **Object 2** and pop/remove **Object 0** since they both have exact same myfield

Would it be possible to do this using lodash?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [_.uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy)

```
let arr = [ {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: ""}, {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9666-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: ""}, {myfield: "1f974a20-aa59-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 0, value: "One"}, {myfield: "af7401a0-aa6e-11e8-9653-ab3419ed3bc9", order: 1, value: "Two"}];

let result = _.uniqBy(arr, 'myfield');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try deep equating the array of objects using the `isEqual` and `uniqWith` methods.

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
```

Here is the link to the documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqWith